# Contained DB Collation error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, collation, except, contained-database

When changing a database to partially contained I am getting the following error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS"
>   and "Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC" in the EXCEPT operation.
>
> Errors were encountered in the procedure 'RSExecRole.DeleteExtensionModuleDDL' 
>   during compilation of the > object. Either the containment option of the database 'VeeamOne' was
>   changed, or this object was present in model db and the user tried to
>   create a new contained database.
>      ALTER DATABASE statement failed. The containment option of the database 'VeeamOne' could not be altered because compilation errors
>   were encountered during validation of SQL modules. See previous
>   errors.
>       ALTER DATABASE statement failed. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

The object this is reporting on I think is from SSRS. However the DB I am changing the collation on is a completely separate application.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

=========================================================================
OK this is the code for the proc, not sure what about it causes it to no be able to be contained though

```
USE [VeeamOne]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [reporter].[DeleteExtensionModuleDDL]    Script Date: 02/12/2015 12:06:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [reporter].[DeleteExtensionModuleDDL]
@EMID int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @Debug bit;
set @Debug = 0;
declare @Emulate bit;
set @Emulate = 0;
declare @reportPackDestructorFunctionName nvarchar(max)
exec @reportPackDestructorFunctionName = [reporter].GenerateExtensionModuleDestructorName @EMID
if exists(select * from sys.objects where (object_id = OBJECT_ID(@reportPackDestructorFunctionName) and type in (N'P', N'PC')))
begin
exec @reportPackDestructorFunctionName
declare @objectsToDelete as table (Name nvarchar(2048), Type nvarchar(2048))
insert @objectsToDelete exec @reportPackDestructorFunctionName
if @Debug = 1
begin
select * from @objectsToDelete
end
declare @TablesToDelete    as table(ObjectID int, Name varchar(max))
declare @FunctionsToDelete   as Table(Name nvarchar(max))
declare @StoredProceduresToDelete as Table(Name nvarchar(max))
declare @AssembliesToDelete   as Table(Name nvarchar(max))
declare @ViewsToDelete    as Table(Name nvarchar(max))
insert into @TablesToDelete
select object_id(Name), Name
from @objectsToDelete
where Type = 'Table'
insert into @FunctionsToDelete
select Name
from @objectsToDelete
where Type = 'Function'
insert into @StoredProceduresToDelete
select Name
from @objectsToDelete
where Type = 'Procedure'
union
select @reportPackDestructorFunctionName
insert into @AssembliesToDelete
select Name
from @objectsToDelete
where Type = 'Assembly'
insert into @ViewsToDelete
select Name
from @objectsToDelete
where Type = 'View'
declare @DependencyTree as Table(ForeignKeyObjectID int, ForeignKeyObjectName nvarchar(max),
ParentTableID int, ParentTableName nvarchar(max),
ChildTableID int, ChildTableName nvarchar(max), Generation int)
declare @Generation int;
set @Generation = 0;
insert into @DependencyTree
select  distinct(fk.object_id) as ForeignKeyObjectID, fk.name as ForeignKeyObjectName,
fk.referenced_object_id as ParentTableID, parent.name as ParentTableName,
fk.parent_object_id as ChildTableID, child.name as ChildTableName, @Generation
from  sys.foreign_keys as fk
inner join sys.objects as parent
on   fk.referenced_object_id = parent.object_id
inner join sys.objects as child
on   fk.parent_object_id = child.object_id
where  fk.referenced_object_id in (select ObjectID from @TablesToDelete)
while @@ROWCOUNT > 0
begin
set @Generation = @Generation + 1
insert into @DependencyTree
select  fk.object_id as ForeignKeyObjectID, fk.name as ForeignKeyObjectName,
fk.referenced_object_id as ParentTableID, parent.name as ParentTableName,
fk.parent_object_id as ChildTableID, child.name as ChildTableName, @Generation
from  @DependencyTree dt
inner join sys.foreign_keys as fk
on   fk.referenced_object_id = dt.ChildTableID
inner join sys.objects as parent
on   fk.referenced_object_id = parent.object_id
inner join sys.objects as child
on   fk.parent_object_id = child.object_id
except
select  ForeignKeyObjectID, ForeignKeyObjectName,
ParentTableID, ParentTableName,
ChildTableID, ChildTableName, @Generation
from  @DependencyTree
end
declare @clearScript as table(ID int primary key identity (0,1), ScriptText nvarchar(max))
insert into @clearScript
select  'alter table [reporter].[' + ChildTableName +
'] drop constraint [' + ForeignKeyObjectName + ']'
from  @DependencyTree
where  ParentTableName in (select Name from @TablesToDelete)
insert into @clearScript
select 'drop table [reporter].[' + Name + ']' from @TablesToDelete
insert into @clearScript
select 'drop function [reporter].[' + Name + ']'
from @FunctionsToDelete
insert into @clearScript
select 'drop procedure [reporter].[' + Name + ']'
from @StoredProceduresToDelete
insert into @clearScript
select 'drop assembly [reporter].[' + Name + ']'
from @AssembliesToDelete
insert into @clearScript
select 'drop view [reporter].[' + Name + ']'
from @ViewsToDelete
if @Debug = 1
begin
select * from @clearScript
end
declare @str nvarchar(max)
declare @ID int;
set @ID  = 0;
declare @MaxID int
select @MaxID = MAX(ID) from @clearScript
print ''
while @ID <= @MaxID
begin
select @str = ScriptText from @clearScript where ID = @ID
if @Emulate = 1
print(@str)
else
exec sp_executesql @statement = @str
set @ID = @ID + 1
end
end
END
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for `'RSExecRole.DeleteExtensionModuleDDL`? And is the instance's default collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS`? And what is the default collation of the `VeeamOne` DB?

Comment: Hi, the instance default collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and the database default is Latin1_General_CI_AS.  As for the object I am searching for that.

Comment: OK have posted the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is a conflict between the collation of the metadata in the system Views -- `sys.foreign_keys` and `sys.objects` -- and the table variable `@DependencyTree`.

As pointed out in @RLF's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122191/30859), the collation of database metadata changes from DATABASE_DEFAULT (in your case `Latin1_General_CI_AS`) to CATALOG_DEFAULT (always `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_WS_KS_SC`) when altering the database to be "contained". This affects the `name` fields being returned in this query:

```sql
SELECT fk.object_id AS [ForeignKeyObjectID], fk.name AS [ForeignKeyObjectName],
       fk.referenced_object_id AS [ParentTableID], parent.name AS [ParentTableName],
       fk.parent_object_id AS ChildTableID, child.name AS [ChildTableName], @Generation
FROM   @DependencyTree dt
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
        ON fk.referenced_object_id = dt.ChildTableID
INNER JOIN sys.objects parent
        ON fk.referenced_object_id = parent.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.objects  child
        ON fk.parent_object_id = child.[object_id]

EXCEPT

SELECT ForeignKeyObjectID, ForeignKeyObjectName,
       ParentTableID, ParentTableName,
       ChildTableID, ChildTableName, @Generation
FROM   @DependencyTree
```

The `fk.name`, `parent.name`, and `child.name` fields are all initially collated as `Latin1_General_CI_AS` but then change to `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_WS_KS_SC` when you ALTER the database to make it "contained".

The error is being thrown because the string fields in both parts of the `EXCEPT` need to have matching collations. But the other part of the `EXCEPT` is using the table variable which is defined as:

```sql
DECLARE @DependencyTree as Table(ForeignKeyObjectID INT,
     ForeignKeyObjectName NVARCHAR(MAX), ParentTableID INT, ParentTableName NVARCHAR(MAX),
ChildTableID INT, ChildTableName NVARCHAR(MAX), Generation INT)
```

No collations are specified for the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` fields (which technically should be declared as `sysname` -- always all lower-case for that one -- since that is the datatype of the source system Views of `sys.objects` and `sys.foreign_keys`). While it is not mentioned in the [Contained Database Collations Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929080.aspx) MSDN page, unlike temporary tables, table variables get their default collation from the database, not from `tempdb` (which is why you didn't see this error in the past since your `tempdb` collation should be `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` since that is the instance collation; you would have gotten this error before if this table were a temporary table). So the collation used for the `ForeignKeyObjectName`, `ParentTableName`, and `ChildTableName` fields was `Latin1_General_CI_AS` and will still be that same collation upon the database being "contained".

Changing that table variable declaration to be the following should resolve this issue:

```sql
DECLARE @DependencyTree Table
(
  ForeignKeyObjectID INT,
  ForeignKeyObjectName sysname COLLATE CATALOG_DEFAULT,
  ParentTableID INT,
  ParentTableName sysname COLLATE CATALOG_DEFAULT,
  ChildTableID INT,
  ChildTableName sysname COLLATE CATALOG_DEFAULT,
  Generation INT
);
```

Using `COLLATE CATALOG_DEFAULT` will work with databases when they are not contained and when they are altered to be contained since `CATALOG_DEFAULT` resolves to the database default in non-contained databases. Another way of stating this behavior is that since database metadata is collated as `CATALOG_DEFAULT` in either state of the database, it will work in the table variable (and temporary tables) in either state of the database.

Answer (score 5):

The MSDN page on [Contained Database Collations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929080.aspx) has some guidance which includes:

- In a contained database, the catalog collation Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_WS_KS_SC. This collation is the **same for all contained databases on all instances of SQL Server and cannot be changed**.

So, your problem is with the **catalog collation**.  As you change to contained, it is changing the database's **catalog collation** to **Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_WS_KS_SC** which is the source of your problem.

Perhaps the comments on collation, particulary the **CATALOG_DEFAULT** may provide you some assistance:

- The **database collation is retained**, but is only used as the default collation for **user data**.
- A new keyword, **CATALOG_DEFAULT**, is available in the COLLATE clause. This is used as a *shortcut to the **current collation of metadata** in both contained and non-contained databases*.

**Crossing Between Contained and Uncontained Contexts**

- As long as a session in a contained database remains contained, it must remain within the database to which it connected. In this case the behavior is very straightforward. But if a session crosses between contained and non-contained contexts, the behavior becomes more complex, since the two sets of rules must be bridged.

And this link ends with the **Conclusion:**

- The collation behavior of contained databases differs subtly from that in non-contained databases. This behavior is generally beneficial, providing instance-independence and simplicity. *Some users may have issues, particularly when a session accesses both contained and non-contained databases.*

**Regarding Data Collation Issues**:

If you *also have to* resolve collation problems on the **data** by using `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT`.  Likely your two databases have the same collation for the data.  But if not, you can use the following technique:

```
select NameValue COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT from MyDatabase.Schema.Table
EXCEPT
select NameValue COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT from TheirDatabase.Schema.Table
```

The value of this approach is that you do not need to specify a particular collation, but `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` allows you to use the collation of the current database.  This would resolve *data collation issues*.

Comment: Yes, in my case I am just using the GUI to change the database to partially contained and getting the said error.   I am at a loss.

Comment: @Tom - Added details based on a better understanding of your issue.  Most SSMS GUI actions can be used to generate a script.  If you use the GUI for that function, generate the script and paste it into a query window.  That will give you a chance to examine the commands and perhaps make a needed change to the script.

Comment: Unfortunately scripting the ALTER Database statement is only a single command when changing to contained.  I will try profiler however.

Answer (score 0):

This is to show a workaround I implemented - if your hands are tied and you cannot alter source tables that are causing a comparison error, this works: Insert the values you need to compare into a temp table that has the COLLATE CATALOG_DEFAULT attribute as mentiond above.

```
 /* This is an interesting problem I ran across while trying to do some work in a collated database. 
The SQLLogin column on the LoginsReference table is nvarchar(50) (yes, it should be sysname)
When trying to see if [name] from the sys.sysusers table existed in the LoginsReference table, I got the following error:

--Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC" in the equal to operation.

My temporary solution is to leverage implicit conversion to insert the SQLLogins FROM LoginsReference into a temp table that is properly collated, and use it for the comparison operator.
Long term solution is to properly collate things in tables.  However, there is a lot of dynamic SQL involved and I'm worried there will be many more issues with other comparisons made in stored procedures elsewhere.  We'll see.
*/
--this is a script to clean out users created in testing and also reset all tables involved in testing.
USE [_Contained Database]
DECLARE @UUID smallint
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @loginname nvarchar (20)
DECLARE @stop bit
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#usernames') is NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #usernames
CREATE TABLE #usernames
([sqlLogin] nvarchar (50) COLLATE CATALOG_DEFAULT)
INSERT INTO #userNames
SELECT [sqlLogin] FROM [dbo].[LoginsReference]


WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 [UID] FROM sys.sysusers WHERE [uid] BETWEEN 5 and 16000 and [name] in (SELECT [sqlLogin] FROM #usernames))
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @loginname = [name] FROM sys.sysusers WHERE [uid] BETWEEN 5 and 16000 and [name] in (SELECT [sqlLogin] FROM #usernames)
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP USER ' + @loginname
    exec sp_executesql @sql
END
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[LoginRoles]
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[LoginsReference]
```

FROM: https://github.com/scorellis/SQLTutorials/blob/master/COLLATE_Comparison_problem

Comment: Hi there. This is actually an unnecessary waste of time and I/O (in `tempdb`: create table, load table, drop table, plus those events in the tran log). All that is needed here is to add `COLLATE` to the inner `SELECT` statements, as in: `(SELECT [sqlLogin] COLLATE CATALOG_DEFAULT FROM [dbo].[LoginsReference])`.

Comment: Your way: 
Table Scan Count Logical Reads Physical Reads Read-Ahead Reads LOB Logical Reads LOB Physical Reads LOB Read-Ahead Reads % Logical Reads of Total Reads
CMDSALoginsReference 200 600 0 0 0 0 0 50.000
sysowners 200 600 0 0 0 0 0 50.000
Total 400 1,200 0 0 0 0 0  
CPU Elapsed
SQL Server parse and compile time: 00:00:00.000 00:00:00.000
SQL Server Execution Times: 00:00:00.016 00:00:00.375
Total 00:00:00.016 00:00:00.375

Comment: My Way:  #usernames__________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000046 200 207 0 0 0 0 0 25.587
CMDSALoginsReference 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0.247
sysowners 200 600 0 0 0 0 0 74.166
Total 401 809 0 0 0 0 0  
CPU Elapsed
SQL Server parse and compile time: 00:00:00.006 00:00:00.011
SQL Server Execution Times: 00:00:00.032 00:00:00.234
Total 00:00:00.038 00:00:00.245

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Iirc, my way is sargable, yours is not.  I might be using "sargable" incorrectly, but putting conversions on the left side of the equality is never a good idea.  ESPECIALLY against system views.

Comment: FYI - both of those ^^ tested 100 iterations of the loop and I didn't actually execute the DROP command as part of it.

Comment: Lemme check it out. How many rows do you typically have in `LoginsReference`? And how many in `sys.sysusers`? SARGable usually refers to if the column can use an index or not, and wrapping a column in a function, or changing its datatype or collation can prevent that. But I don't see that as being an issue here for either of our approaches since nothing modifies `sysusers.name` in the `IN` predicate. HOWEVER, I just realized that all of this is moot since neither the loop nor the `EXISTS` is required. You can simplify this down to a single `SELECT` statement that concats all `DROP` statements.

Comment: Just do the following: `SET @SQL = N''; SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'DROP USER ' + QUOTENAME(usr.[name]) + N';' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)
FROM sys.sysusers usr
INNER JOIN [dbo].[LoginsReference] lgn
ON lgn.[sqlLogin] COLLATE CATALOG_DEFAULT = usr.[name]
WHERE  usr.[uid] BETWEEN 5 AND 16000;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;`

Comment: this is on a system being used to test the project that creates logins, so there could be (conceivably) hundreds of users that need to be removed.  The most I've personally created before tearing down and rebuilding is about 30.

Comment: I will look at your code sample, thanks.  I've always had a weird mental block around shoving a log of rows from a select statement into a variable and then executing it.  It's one of those things I've seen other people do, but I'm too much of a control freak to do it.  (I probably just need to get over myself :) )

Comment: Hey there. If you want control, you can either use a cursor, or you can structure the Dynamic SQL to be calls to `EXEC`. I've done that before to break up _really_ large sets into smaller chunks. It does complicate using strings when you have multiple layers, but it does work to create smaller batches (since you can't use `GO`). And I don't think you need to be concerned with the volume of `DELETE` statements anyway. I submitted a [PR for your code](https://github.com/scorellis/SQLTutorials/pull/1) as it made it much easier to show the options and provide a test for dropping 800 Users :-)