# Collation conflict ... Could not use dbo.sysdac_instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore, collation, msdb

After a migration of databases to a new 2014 server with default collation Latin1_General_CI_AS, but where most of the databases have a collation of Latin1_General_BIN, an attempt to import an Excel spreadsheet is throwing the following error:

[image: Collation conflict error message]

I've tracked sysdac_instances down to msdb where it is a system view and querying it directly gives the same error. I'm hoping someone will be able to point me in the direction of a straighforward-ish solution to this problem?

Curiously though, running the import via SSMS 2008 works.

Comment: what collation is the msdb database?  Latin1_General_BIN?

Comment: Yes, msdb is  Latin1_General_BIN.

Answer (score 7):

The `sysdac_instances` view is defined as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[sysdac_instances]
AS
    SELECT
        -- this must be locked down because we use instance_id visability as a security gate
        case 
            when (dbo.fn_sysdac_is_currentuser_sa() = 1) then dac_instances.instance_id
            when sd.owner_sid = SUSER_SID() then dac_instances.instance_id
            else NULL
        end as instance_id,
        dac_instances.instance_name,
        dac_instances.type_name,
        dac_instances.type_version,
        dac_instances.description,
        case 
            when (dbo.fn_sysdac_is_currentuser_sa() = 1) then dac_instances.type_stream
            when sd.owner_sid = SUSER_SID() then dac_instances.type_stream
            else NULL
        end as type_stream,
        dac_instances.date_created,
        dac_instances.created_by,
        dac_instances.instance_name as database_name
    FROM sysdac_instances_internal dac_instances
    LEFT JOIN sys.databases sd
        ON dac_instances.instance_name = sd.name
```

The view performs a join on `instance_name` against the `sys.databases.name` column.  Since the column definition for the `sysdac_instances_internal.instance_name` does not specify a collation, it will assume the collation of the msdb database.

Perhaps you restored msdb from an instance where the collation was `Latin1_General_BIN`, which would cause the collation conflict.  If that *is* the case, you'd need to recreate the MSDB database, since its [collation cannot be altered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187112.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

While @Max is [correct](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133985/30859) about a) the root cause of this error (collation of restored `msdb` database does not match the server's default collation, which is used to set the collation of the `name` field in `master.sys.sysdbreg` -- the actual source of the `name` field in `sys.databases`), and b) that ideally you would rebuild `msdb` to have a collation matching the server's default (i.e. `Latin1_General_CI_AS`), there are two short-term solutions to get your import working until you can implement that ideal solution (and yes, I tried both and they do work :-):

1. Alter the definition of the `dbo.sysdac_instances` View to explicitly state the Collation which will bypass the conflict due to default collation precedence behavior:

   ```sql
   ALTER VIEW [dbo].[sysdac_instances]
   AS
       SELECT
           -- this must be locked down because we use instance_id visability as a security gate
           case 
               when (dbo.fn_sysdac_is_currentuser_sa() = 1) then dac_instances.instance_id
               when sd.owner_sid = SUSER_SID() then dac_instances.instance_id
               else NULL
           end as instance_id,
           dac_instances.instance_name,
           dac_instances.type_name,
           dac_instances.type_version,
           dac_instances.description,
           case 
               when (dbo.fn_sysdac_is_currentuser_sa() = 1) then dac_instances.type_stream
               when sd.owner_sid = SUSER_SID() then dac_instances.type_stream
               else NULL
           end as type_stream,
           dac_instances.date_created,
           dac_instances.created_by,
           dac_instances.instance_name as database_name
       FROM sysdac_instances_internal dac_instances
       LEFT JOIN sys.databases sd
           ON dac_instances.instance_name = sd.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
   ```

   I pulled that definition straight from the DB using `SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('dbo.sysdac_instances'));` and then just added the `COLLATE` clause at the end.

   I used the `Latin1_General_CI_AS` Collation in the `COLLATE` clause to add in, rather than the binary Collation, so that this operation (i.e. matching on database names) would behave like any other comparison to `sys.databases.name` (that was, of course, not overriden using a COLLATE clause ;-)
2. Alter the collation of the field in question:

   ```sql
   USE [msdb];

   ALTER TABLE dbo.[sysdac_instances_internal]
         DROP CONSTRAINT [UQ_sysdac_instances_internal];

   ALTER TABLE dbo.[sysdac_instances_internal]
         ALTER COLUMN [instance_name] sysname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL;

   ALTER TABLE dbo.[sysdac_instances_internal]
         ADD CONSTRAINT [UQ_sysdac_instances_internal]
         UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([instance_name] ASC);
   ```

Between the two options, #1 (i.e. altering the View) would have the least chance of adversely affecting other stuff within the `msdb` database using the underlying table.

If you are considering updating the collation of the instance and database(s), then please see the following post of mine:

[Changing the Collation of the Instance, the Databases, and All Columns in All User Databases: What Could Possibly Go Wrong?](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/06/11/changing-the-collation-of-the-instance-and-all-columns-across-all-user-databases-what-could-possibly-go-wrong/)

Other notes:

- I am guessing that the import worked in SSMS 2008 most likely due to its code not referencing this particular View. I can't think of any other difference that could explain that behavior.
- When using binary collations, it is best to use the newer `BIN2` collations and not the deprecated `BIN` collations.
- When possible, it is best to use the newest version of a particular Collation, and picking a variation of it that ends in `_SC`, if one is available. In the case of your new server, a better choice would have been: `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC`.
- This is another example of why we need to have a special collation similar to `DATABASE_DEFAULT` but working at the instance level — `INSTANCE_DEFAULT` — so that there can be a generic solution to this type of issue. This would allow the `msdb.dbo.sysdac_instances_internal` table to be created using:

  ```
  ...
  [instance_name]   sysname COLLATE INSTANCE_DEFAULT,
  ...
  ```

  Or, it could be that the `msdb.dbo.sysdac_instances` view has this at the end:

  ```
  LEFT JOIN sys.databases sd
      ON dac_instances.instance_name = sd.name COLLATE INSTANCE_DEFAULT
  ```

  So please vote for the following suggestion:

  [Add special collation INSTANCE_DEFAULT to work like COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT but uses instance's default collation](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/36197932-add-special-collation-instance-default-to-work-lik)

Comment: +1'd - Interesting answer, but wouldn't altering a system view put you at risk of not being supported by Microsoft?

Comment: @MaxVernon I guess it depends on what needs supporting. While those two objects are `is_ms_shipped = 1`, `sysdac_instances_internal` is a User Table, not a System Table, so I would assume the same for the View.  As I said, certainly not ideal, but much quicker than rebuilding `msdb` so at least a means of moving forward. Also, I don't see any harm in altering the View since it doesn't affect how other stuff works, it merely allows this to work.

Comment: agreed.  I'd alter the view myself, and just move on.

Comment: Many thanks all for the input. Altering the view would seem to be the easiest and safest option here. Gordon.

Answer (score 2):

In general collations can be persuaded to match one another.  See my comments at:
[Contained DB Collation error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122186/contained-db-collation-error/122191#122191)

Perhaps the comments on collation, particulary the CATALOG_DEFAULT, may provide you some assistance:

- The database collation is retained, but is only used as the default collation for **user data**.
- A new keyword, CATALOG_DEFAULT, is available in the COLLATE clause. This is used as a *shortcut to the **current collation of metadata** in both contained and non-contained databases.*

For more straightforward collation problems, such as between two databases, a sample query from that discussion is:

```
select NameValue COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT from MyDatabase.Schema.Table
EXCEPT
select NameValue COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT from TheirDatabase.Schema.Table
```

The value of this approach is that you do not need to specify a particular collation, but COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT allows you to use the collation of the current database. This would resolve data collation issues.

Comment: How does this apply to a system view, whose definition cannot be altered?

Comment: @MaxVernon - I understood the CATALOG_DEFAULT was used to overcome the metadata collation problem. Appreciate any clarification you have. *But I certainly agree that having the same collation is the best answer.*

Comment: I've certainly managed to amend a couple of queries that were throwing the same collation conflicts by using COLLATE DEFAULT_DATABASE however I was uncertain about amending a system view, although srutzky has mentioned that below as being the lesser of the evils.

Comment: @YaHozna While `DEFAULT_DATABASE` is a very handy option in many cases, I would not recommend it for your situation. The `msdb` database has a binary collation while the server (i.e. other system DBs) have a case-insensitive Collation. By using `DEFAULT_DATABASE` you are making the operation use the binary Collation while most other operations against server meta-data will be case-insensitive. I would think it better to prefer the server's default Collation, which is now `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.